# When a wattle-and-daub construction was demolished, how did they recycle or dispose of the materials?

Tags: middle-ages, resource, cities, construction

In the medieval age, when a wattle-and-daub building had to be demolished, did they recycle the materials? Especially the logs of the frames, these seem to be prime targets for reuse.

[This article](https://www.buildingconservation.com/articles/wattleanddaub/wattleanddaub.htm) claims that even the daub could be recycled:

> [...] *Old daub salvaged from damaged panels can be broken up and mixed with a little water to make it useable again. It may be necessary to add additional material to bulk it out, or modify its performance.*  [...]

However, it does not make any remark if this is a modern or old technique.

There's references to successful reuse of timbers and logs from demolished or deconstructed buildings, but these also don't make references to historical periods past.

If they didn't recycle anything, how did they dispose of the materials? Burning (probably not, the whole city was flammable)? Carting it away?

Answer (score -2):

Though I am sure that the mud and poo part of the wattle and daub could be recycled.  Recycling was not a major issue with non precious materials in Britain.  Time Team Videos where I have seen most of the wattle and daub construction the only claim for me to have any knowledge of such a building, Daub being a mixture of mud and excrement, used to add fiber to bind it together and the wattle, interlaced/woven sticks or twigs, the lattice.  they smeared the daub thickly on to seal the spaces in the woven branches to create walls between the posts of round houses, why would you desire to recycle,instead of to repair or replace, The need to do anything with it would lead me to believe the twigs are rotted or moldy due to water hitting it, which means the thatch roof with a large overhang also needs repair, because it extends so that the walls only get wet from rain when it is really windy.  This type of construction predates The Romans entry into Britain for sure, though how many hundreds of years it does, I am uncertain, I believe that 60 CE is around the time of the Roman invasion of Britain, but that is straight out of memory, Time Team Episodes do cover quite a bit on YouTube, of the methods and periods of such construction.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Well, I know in some villages in Bangladesh where they use wattle and daub they do reuse material. Its a sustainable. But that is not a term they would use. I think they see it as merely efficient use of resources.

Answer (score -3):

Disposal was usually either intentional, by people that wanted to kill you, or unintentional because they had a fire in the center that had no chimney and could very easily catch fire, the round house had no termite control no rot prevention, maintaining them was usually performed by adding material where things failed, when that got to be to big a job they would often burn it down and move into a new home.  Cremation was a thing back then.  Some Archeologist figure that they believed the home had a soul or presence and was treated as a buried member of their family. Burying sacrifices in the doorway and breaking the door before moving out.

Comment: You should edit additional information into your original answer rather than adding another.